# Which type of NVME SSD

Tags: laptop, ssd

My friend has a 2015 or so laptop for which he wants the hard disk replaced by SSD. It seems its supports NVME type SSD but I can't seem to figure out which one of these it supports - they look the same but have difference minor pricing for specs.

[EVM M.2 (2880) 256GB SATA SSD 3D TLC NAND Flash Internal SSD Fast Performance Ultra Low Power Consumption (EVMM2-256GB, Black)](https://www.amazon.in/EVM-Internal-Performance-Consumption-EVMM2-256GB/dp/B09W31RQP1/)
[image]

[EVM Internal SSD Interface PCle Gen 3x4 Fast Performance, Ultra Low Power Consumption NVME PCIe SSD (EVMNV/256GB, Black, 256GB)](https://www.amazon.in/EVM-Internal-1800MB-EVMNV-256GB/dp/B09F6DNLBD/)
[image]

Which one of these should he go for?

Note: These brands seem Asian specific - I am interested in knowing the hardware specific compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a 2015 laptop, it probably does not support NVMe and NVMe SSD's like the Kingston A2000 of that bottem SSD probably won't physically fit. Try getting a SATA M.2 SSD like this one: https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/932779/wd-blue-ssd-m2-3d-v-nand-tlc-1tb.html (WD Blue SSD)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.kingston.com/en/blog/pc-performance/two-types-m2-vs-ssd

https://www.pcworld.com/article/558324/nvme-vs-m-2-vs-sata-ssd-whats-the-difference.html

> he wants the hard disk replaced by SSD

SSD = *solid state disk* which is an umbrella term for any *solid state* disk which includes the m.2 form factor versus the 2.5" ssd **that may already be within the laptop.**  You said *hard disk* which, being a 2015 laptop, likely has a 2.5" disk, whether it is an SSD or a slow spinning traditional hard disk I don't know.  Now there are 2.5" size hard disks, that have been used in laptops, what years that was common I don't remember... before SSD's came down in price and became the norm in laptops.

> I can't seem to figure out which one of these it supports

smart thing to do what be to look at make/model/serial of laptop and check with manufacturer to get the correct info on what the laptop can support, and also double check the *hard disk* that is already in the laptop.  If it already has a 2.5" SATA SSD (hard drive) and you want to go with a M.2 SATA SSD you are not gaining anything.  Support for NVME M.2 is not common, most M.2 is SATA.  If you post make/model/serial of laptop as a comment anyone here can look that info up in 30 seconds probably.